# Jquery UI_datepicker in Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, uidatepicker, formtastic, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am relatively new to Rails but not to programming... I've spent way more time than is 'sane' to try to resolve this to no avail...

I am using Ruby 1.92, Rails 3.1, formtastic 2.1 w/ the ui_datepicker-rails3, a wrapper for the jquery datepicker widget

https://github.com/kristianmandrup/ui_datepicker-rails3

The problematic VIEW has this very simple line (this is the line #18 referenced in the error:

```
<%= f.input :birthdate, :as => :ui_date_picker %>
```

When I click on the textbox, the jquery datapicker appears and works fine, but on submit I keep getting:

> I18n::ArgumentError in Devise/registrations#create
>
> Showing C:/Sites/sl2/app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb where line #18 raised:
>
> Object must be a Date, DateTime or Time object. "04 May 2012" given.

**My 'newb' hunch is that the date widget outputs as a String, and that the model expects a date (birthdate is a Date).**

So I tried various conversions
    def birthdate= (value)

```
begin
  require 'date'
    date_parsed=Date.parse(value)
    write_attribute(:birthdate, date_parsed)
    puts date_parsed
    @bad_date=nil
  rescue
    write_attribute(:birthdate, nil)
    @bad_date = value
  end
end
```

-- which causes other issues...
This seems like it should be so much simpler... What am I missing?!

Comment: If your birthdate string is like "04 May 2012" than you can just use the `.to_date` method to receive a valid date in rails. Just do `"04 May 2012".to_date` in your birthdate method.

Comment: Except that my date isn't being output like that, the textbox is populate with a regular 04/05/2012 date.... Also, shouldn't Date.parse take care of turning a string into a date?

I've tried to_date earlier, will try again

Comment: `to_date` works for me also on a string like "04/05/2012": `>> "04/05/2012".to_date #=> Fri, 04 May 2012`

Comment: Still not working... I agree 100% with your logic, which is what is confusing me so much...

When I look at the REQUEST, which appears on the error page, birthdate is clearly a date:
 "birthdate"=>"2012-04-27",

In the model:
    def birthdate= (value)
         begin
      require 'date'
      write_attribute(:birthdate, value.to_date)
      rescue
        @bad_date = value
      end
 end

Comment: This seems really strange to me. Did you try the rails `date_select("modelname", "attributename")`? See here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-date_select

Comment: I am using Formtastic for forms... Actually, this gave me an idea, when I reverted to the standard formtastic date-picker (3 drop downs) - it didn't complain at all... What it posted that time was: user[birthdate(1i)] 2009

But I don't like the drop-downs for dates, date-picker so much sexier...Alas, TBC...
user[birthdate(2i)] 4
user[birthdate(3i)] 16

Comment: Yeah but rails should joins the strange `user[:birthdate(1i)]` into a date at `user[:birthdate]`. But yeah you are right, the frontent is quite unsexy. Waiting for the html5 datetime select stuff :)

Comment: I find it very strange that it accepts a request with a 3 part date, but denies a single date... 'tis driving me crazy... Thanks for your help though

Answer (score 0):

You can format the date in the model or in the controller or change the format that the datepicker outputs like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('input.ui-date-picker').datepicker({dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"});
});
```

I have the datepicker output a long readable format and then use a gem "delocalize" to do the conversion on save;

https://github.com/clemens/delocalize

OR your setter needs to return a dateobject or nil

```
def birthdate= (value)
  self.birthdate = value.to_date
end
```

Comment: I don't think it has to do with the format... I've played with the format backwards and forwards... I have a feeling that this is somehow related to devise or language, what exactly is a "I18n::ArgumentError"?

Comment: It looks like your validations are failing on create and when the form is re-rendered it cant localize the date. Have you tried removing your setter and just sending in the date in the correct format '2012-01-26'

Comment: Yes it is because you are returning @bad_date = value and value is not a date object.